# CSS background-color for body element not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot get the body to change its background color. All the other CSS attributes apply perfectly to the other elements.

```js
document.getElementById('color').onclick = changeColor;
var currentColor = "red";

function changeColor() {
  if (currentColor == "red") {
    document.body.style.color = "green";
    currentColor = "green";
  } else {
    document.body.style.color = "red";
    currentColor = "red";
  }
  return currentColor;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: red;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, Arial;
  font-size: 38px;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial;
}

button {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1> This is a header.</h1>

<button id="color">Change the color</button>

<p> Paragraph testing two.</p>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.cnn.com">CNN</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/rhv2cfun/

Comment: The code is correct, inspect the page and see if the css is override by another css

Comment: You are setting the body correctly, possibly the body does not fill-up the whole page and or gets covered by other elements.

Comment: The Javascript only changes the text color. Why do you expect the background color to change?

Answer (score 0):

At first this can be apply with !important directive such as

```
body {
 background-color: #E7E7E7 !important;
}
```

If you need more help, please give more detail about the project or page. It can be also inherit some another CSS directives or classes or It may include style directives.

If you share page code the solution can be more faster.

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of `!important` unless it's absolutely necessary. Add more specificity to the selector instead (i.e. `html > body`).

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Your previews code I can't get your full code. Now check this  https://codepen.io/bravotanmoy/pen/bRpEbL

HTML

```
<button id="color" onclick="changeColor()">Change the color</button>

<div id="white"></div>
<div id="not-white"></div>
```

CSS

```
 body {
  background-color: yellow;  
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#white {
  background: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#not-white {
  background:#e7e7e7;
}
```

JavaScript

```
//document.getElementById('color').onclick = changeColor();
var currentColor = "red";

function changeColor() {
        if(currentColor == "red"){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "green";
        currentColor = "green";
        }
        else{
        document.body.style.backgroundColor  = "red";
        currentColor = "red";
        }
        return currentColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this simple css, create new unique ID in css, ex: david

```
.david {
  background-color: #19529C;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Then match the html code on your website for the class, usually like a section

Like this:

```
<section id="unique id" class="david">
```

Add here your content

```
</section>
```